# How to find if function is static at compile time

Tags: c++, static, macros

I have logging macro which logs the this pointer of the function but the problem is when logging macro used in static function which doesn't have this pointer and I get compilation error.

e.g

```
LOG_DEBUG(msg,...) \
   Log::WriteLog(Log::LOG_DEBUG, __FILE__, __LINE__, _FUNC_NAME_, this, msg, ## __VA_ARGS__);
```

I was wondering if there was a way to check if the current method is static than I can either use this pointer or pass null and avoid compilation error.

Please let me know if GNU provide any predefine macros to determine if current function is static or any alternate way.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid trying to auto detect and make it the responsibility of the developer.
Just provide another logging macros for situations where this is no this value.
The compiler will generate an error when you use LOG_DEBUG() incorrectly and you can replace.

```
LOG_NON_OO_DEBUG(msg,...) \
   Log::WriteLog(Log::LOG_DEBUG, __FILE__, __LINE__, _FUNC_NAME_, msg, ## __VA_ARGS__);
```

Note: I would not pass NULL (or 0 either).
I would overload the WriteLog() method so that it has a version that does not require a this pointer.

Comment: thx for the answer.  As a good lazy programmer, I was trying to avoid duplication of macros and replacing into existing code based on method is static or not. So thought if there was a way to findout at compile time similar to boost static check, would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Martin's answer, *this* is a compile-time construct, whereas macros are pre-processor, so there's no way to test for the existence of *this* with a macro.  In less strongly typed languages like perl you can check whether a symbol is defined, but since C/C++ are strongly typed there's no need for such an operator.

*edit*

I want to clarify the point I was trying to make in the above paragraph a bit.

The pre-processor is a Cism.  If I had to bet, it probably has seen only bug fixes and minor changes to its behavior but otherwise is nearly identical in behavior to C from 20 years ago.  In other words, the pre-processor isn't designed to work on language-specific features.

Language features like *static*, *this*, calling conventions, types, etc ... the pre-processor isn't aware of them, and doesn't have logic for working with them.  The only way this could  be pulled off is if a language feature exists to test the definedness of *this*, or test to see whether you're in a static function or not.

*/edit*

I'm inclined to suggest you use a non-macro approach to logging, or a less macro-dependent solution.  The only advantage I see to using macros is you don't have to type out `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` all over the place.  In that respect I don't see an issue with wrapping whatever you come up with in a macro.

For example, you could add a generic function to your classes that generates a terse piece of information, something like:

```
class MyClass {
  private:
    void MemberLogMsg();
  public:
    static void LogMsg( MyClass* M = NULL);
};
```

Your macro would always call LogMsg, and as Martin suggested the onus would be on the developer to pass in *this* or not.

Now, I won't stand by the quality of the above example, only by the spirit of what it's meant to express.

Comment: thx for your response.  I do use boost-log and it takes care of most of the things.  It is modifying the existing code where and changing the macros based on static/non-satic and also training to new developers :)